# Netplan on VPS with 5 NICs doesn't work simultaneously

Tags: networking, netplan

I have properly configured the network on my host server and my virtual server (VPS(KVM)) able to communicate and reachable by one of three interfaces. Each of them works well, but I don't know where I wrong because three interfaces don't work simultaneously.

There is my config

**Internal network**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

**External interfaces**

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 51.38.110.9/32
      gateway4: 145.239.244.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      optional: true
      routes:
        - to: 145.239.244.1/32
          via: 51.38.110.9
          scope: link
```

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 51.38.110.8/32
      gateway4: 145.239.244.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      optional: true
      routes:
        - to: 145.239.244.1/32
          via: 51.38.110.8
          scope: link
```

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 51.38.110.7/32
      gateway4: 145.239.244.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      optional: true
      routes:
        - to: 145.239.244.1/32
          via: 51.38.110.7
          scope: link
```

Thank in advance

Comment: How many .yaml files do you have in /etc/netplan? It looks like you've defined enp2s0 three times. Also, you can't specify gateway4 when you specify routes.

Comment: heynnema, I am sorry, I have enp1s0 - enp5s0

Answer (score 0):

precursor to a final .yaml file...

replace all of your .yaml files with this...

I have two examples for you...

## Example #1

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp2s0:
      addresses: [51.38.110.9/32]
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 145.239.244.1/32 # this might be wrong
          via: 51.38.110.9 # this might be wrong
          scope: link
      optional: true
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [51.38.110.8/32]
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 145.239.244.1/32 # this might be wrong
          via: 51.38.110.8 # this might be wrong
          scope: link
      optional: true
    enp4s0:
      addresses: [51.38.110.7/32]
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 145.239.244.1/32 # this might be wrong
          via: 51.38.110.7 # this might be wrong
          scope: link
      optional: true
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

## Example #2

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp2s0:
      addresses: [51.38.110.9/32]
      gateway4: 145.239.244.1 # don't use together with routes:
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      optional: true
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [51.38.110.8/32]
      gateway4: 145.239.244.1 # don't use together with routes:
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      optional: true
    enp4s0:
      addresses: [51.38.110.7/32]
      gateway4: 145.239.244.1 # don't use together with routes:
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.186.33.99
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      optional: true
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Comment: heynnema, thank you. Your config should work.
But, I'm sorry, I posted incorrect config. I have 5 interfaces enp1s0 - enp5s0 and each of them in own yaml file.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko  Is it one PCI card with 4-5 ports, or 4-5 PCI cards with one port each? You have the same MAC address in all three .yaml files... can't be right... correct? You also have gateway4: and routes: together, and you can't do that. Let me know and I'll put together a different .yaml.

Comment: I have removed MAC. In my real config MACs are different. It is VPS with 5 virtual NIC which each of them has own MAC.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko  Let me work on a new .yaml for you...

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko it may not be perfect, but it's a good start. Check the routes addresses.

Comment: You can use the MAC addresses if you assure that you've got them on the correct enpXs0 device.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko status please...

Comment: I have checked MAC set correctly. I deleted one of YAML and reboot. IP works. I.e. all YAML configs work separately but simultaneously works only one.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko did you try either one of my .yaml files... esp the 2nd one?

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko make sure that there aren't any TABS in your .yaml files.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko status please...

Answer (score 0):

All offered solutions didn't work until I had set one MAC for all IP on http://ovh.com. It may not work for another hosting provider.